# iText 7 Create Textbox

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I am looking to create a traditional textbox in iText 7. I have two concerns with CreateText and CreateMultiLineText. My first concern is that there doesn't appear to be a wrapping property on CreateText? Enabling multiLine text just gives enables scrolling, which doesn't fit business requirements unfortunately. Second concern is that the CreateText and/or CreateMultiLineText doesn't seem to support dragging/moving from a user perspective. Has anyone ran into similar frustrations or have workarounds for these issues?

TYIA

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in the wrong spot to create a traditional Textbox. If you're looking to create a Textbox you're going to want to use FreeTextAnnotation. See my code below for an example.

```
                PdfAnnotationBorder border = new PdfAnnotationBorder(1, 1, 1);
                PdfString Content = new PdfString("This is the content of the text-box");
                PdfAnnotation annotation = new PdfFreeTextAnnotation(new Rectangle(250, 720, 300, 50), null)
                    .SetColor(ColorConstants.WHITE)
                    .SetBorder(new PdfArray(new float[] { 0, 0, 2 }))
                    .SetContents(Content);
                    
             
                //annotation.SetRichText(new PdfString("<span style=\"color:#10FF10;\">Hello world</span>"));
                //annotation.SetAppearance

                firstPage.AddAnnotation(annotation);
                pdfDoc.Close();
```